# threading dont work ? getting typeerror 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-multithreading

```
thread1 = Thread(target=monster_goyang(dictMonsterGoyang, dictMonsterGoyang_Rev, endMonster, startMonster, lambda: draw(win, grid, ROWS, width)))
thread2 = Thread(target=algorithm(lambda: draw(win, grid, ROWS, width), grid, start, end))
thread1.daemon = True
thread2.start()
thread1.start()
```

for full code :
[link to python code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15TcEpfmaoBqua-mwp4-NSfZS5Q1-2_dF/view?usp=sharing)

its coding with tim code with my litte own addition

first click to set start point, second click to set end point, consequent click to make wall, right clicking on a point will remove the point

to put down a blue point hold click left mouse button then press v, the same for greenblue point.

to re-enable putting down black point press b

sorry if its a bad question

Comment: Show *the full traceback*, not just the error message.

Comment: You are calling your functions *immediately*, in the main thread, and then using their return values as the function for the thread to execute.  The `target=` parameter should simply be the name of a function, rather than a call to that function; any parameters that function needs are passed separately in the `args=` and `kwargs=` parameters to `Thread()`.

Comment: thanks that help a lot, its working now